# Putting overlays on Bing maps for ios

Tags: bing-maps, overlays

I need to put overlays on a Bing map in iOS, I'm pretty new to the Bing Maps API and xcode so would really appreciate some sample code.

How can you put overlays on Bing maps for iOS?

Answer (score 0):

Use the Bing Maps V7 AJAX control for iOS. The old Bing Maps iOS control is deprecated and can only put pushpins on the map. The AJAX control has all the features of Bing Maps and works great on iOS.